# XPath date inquiry

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have this XML

```
<Table>
<mdate>2014-04-08T00:00:00+03:00</mdate>
<title>Hello</title>
</Table>
```

I want to do search transaction by date I'm trying to use this one

```
//Table[contains(mdate,2014-04-08*)]
```

but it doesn't work

Any hint ?

Thanks

Comment: You need to tell us whether you are using XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 (or even XPath 3.0, since that is now a formal Recommendation!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need wildcard character in this case. You can either use `contains()` function this way :

```
//Table[contains(mdate,'2014-04-08')]
```

or use `starts-with()` function instead :

```
//Table[starts-with(mdate,'2014-04-08')]
```

Both XPath queries above will match `<Table>` element in this question